# How to calculate mod/remainder using SSE?

Tags: assembly, sse, division

What is the best/fastest way to calculate x % M using vector instructions on x64/sse? (By % I mean mod/remainder).

I couldn't find any opcode for packed mod, so I think the best I could do is promote int to float, then calculate x - m * floor(x / m) using DIVPS and ROUNDPS.

Or is there a better alternative that I'm missing?

**UPDATE**: M is only known at runtime, the actual loop looks like this:

```
unsigned x[SIZE], M[SIZE], answer[SIZE];
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
  answer[i] = x[i] % M[i];
}
```

Also M is known to be in the range 1 - 640000000, if it helps in any way.

Comment: It doesn't get much faster than that. In addition, you may need to check for off-by-one rounding errors. The quotient that you compute may not always round to the correct integer if the fractional part is very close to `0.5`.

Comment: Unless M is a power of 2 then I think you're out of luck.

Comment: Is `M` a compile time constant?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24744703/is-there-a-good-way-of-finding-modulus-of-two-variables-using-sse-without-svml/24752762#24752762

Comment: Okay, I understand now, M changes each iteration `M[i]`. The method in my answer won't help you then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `M` is either a compile time constant or is constant within a loop then instead of using division you can [calculated a reciprocal and then do multiplication and a shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Division_by_a_constant). We can write

```
x/M = (x*(2^n/M))>>n
```

The factor `2^n/M` (aka [magic number](https://web.archive.org/web/20131109042939/http://www.hackersdelight.org/magic.htm)) should be calculated before the loop or at compile time.

For example if we want `x[i]/5` and we know that `x[i]` is less than `2^15`  we can use `2^n/M = 0xCCCD` and `n = 18`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 32768
int x[N], y[N], z[N];

int main(void) {
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) x[i] = i;
    int M = 5;
    int fact = 0xCCCD;
    int n = 18;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        y[i] = x[i]/M;
        z[i] = (fact*x[i])>>n;
        if(y[i] != z[i]) printf("%d %d\n", y[i], z[i]);
    }
}
```

There are several different methods to determine the magic number and `n`. I use [Agner Fog's Vector Class Library(VCL)](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass). It does this for you using SSE2 or AVX2 for 32-bit numbers (instead of the 15-bit numbers in the code above). If you want to see assembly code to do this his [assembly library](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#asmlib) also does this for SSE2 (and maybe AVX2)

See page 22 of the VCL manual for more details. It's also described in the manual for his assembly library.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to tell that M is only available at runtime. I'll update the question. Thanks for your answer, I wasn't aware of Fog's VCL and it seems pretty useful.

Comment: @Ricbit `M` does not need to be a compile time constant. It just needs to be constant within a loop. It takes time to calculate `fact` and `n`. If you had to do that for every iteration it would be slower than doing division. But if you compute them before your loop then it's much faster to use multiplication and a shift.

Comment: Turns out I did have a gain by replacing the mod with two multiplications, even without using sse. Thanks again for the idea.

Comment: Should be pointed out that for 16-bit numbers, there's `_mm_mulhi_epu16` to get just the high half (bits `[31:16]`) of each product.  This means you don't have to widen to 32-bit, and in fact should not because SSE4 `pmulld` is slower on Haswell and later.